# What is the most effective algorithm to compare a large number of strings?

Tags: java, algorithm, collections

Let's take 2 string arraylists

```
List<String> namesListA = new ArrayList<>(/*50 000 strings*/);
List<String> namesListB = new ArrayList<>(/*400 000 strings*/);
```

removeAll method seems not working. After:

```
namesListA.removeAll(namesListB);
```

namesListA.size() is still 50000. Edit: Input data was incorrect, it actually works but takes a long lime.

I wrote the following brute-force code:

```
boolean match;
    for (String stringA: namesListA)
    {
        match = false;
        for (String stringB: namesListB)
        {
            if (stringA.equals(stringB))
            {
                match = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!match)
        {
            finallist.add(stringA);
        }
    }
```

But it takes 8 hours to perform. it there any known effective algorithm for searching strings? Like to sort strings in alphabetical order and then search letter by letter or something like this.

Comment: You could sort those list but this will take times too. This will help reduce the number of reading drasticly. Then you could use some dychotomial search to reduce it again. But for that, you need to sort those list. There is [Collections.sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List))

Comment: If `removeAll` isn't removing any, then the lists have no strings in common.

Comment: Are you sure removeAll is not working ??

Comment: whats the intent here? is it to find all the common elements? or find all the distinct elements? or to find if both the ArrayLists match exactly(like all elements in A present in B) ??)

Comment: You can also use `listA.retainAll(listB)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution in **O(n*logn)**. **Should be faster** than the approaches posted yet.
Edit: If you don't need the exact element, my other approach is faster.

**1.) Sort both lists**

Use Collections.sort(...) for efficient sorting in O(n*logn).

**2.) Compare with two iterators**

Fetch two iterators over the two lists. Then:

```
while(leftIterator.hasNext() && rightIterator.hasNext(){
    int comparisonResult = leftElement.compare(rightElement);
    if (comparisonResult == -1){
        leftElement = leftIterator.next();
    }
    else if (comparisonResult == 1){
        rightElement = rightIterator.next();
    }
    else{
        // found it!
        return true;
    }
}
```

(Sorry if I mistyped, don't have an IDE at my hand)

=> Sorting is in O(i*logi + j*logj))

=> Comparison is in O(i+j)

---

Result performance is efficiently in **class O(n*logn)**. This should work nicely.

Comment: You can also sort only the smaller structure `O(n*log(n))`, and iterate over the unsorted one to find a match in the sorted one `O(n*log(n))`.

Comment: Using `Set` you get Linear time complexity, which is better than n*logn

Comment: It looks like you're assuming the elements implement `Comparable`, which is reasonable, but the correct method to call is `compare()`. Also, the result of `compare()` should be tested for being less than or greater than zero, not equal to 1 or -1.

Answer (score 6):

You could put elements of list `namesListB` into a new `Set` (preferably `HashSet`). Then it is much more effective to call `namesListA.removeAll(setFromListB);`, since the implementation of `ArrayList.removeAll` calls `Collection.contains()` which is much more effective in a `Set` (`HashSet`) than in an `ArrayList` (`HashSet.contains()` has constant time performance, while `ArrayList.contains()` has linear performance).

Anyway, `namesListA.removeAll(namesListB);` should work, if `namesListA` doesn't change, then the 2 lists have no elements in common.

Estimation of time complexity (`N = namesListA.length`, `M = namesListB.length`): 
Creating the `HashSet` from `namesListB`: **O(M)** 
Calling `namesListA.removeAll(setListB)`: **O(N * 1) = O(N)** 
In total: **O(M + N)** (which could be written as O(M) since M>N, but I'm not sure)

Comment: @SrikanthA have you read my *whole* answer? I mention this in the last paragraph.

Comment: I meant direct list removeAll as the best algorithm. Considering, you are converting List of 400k to a Set (Which internally does a contains while adding to Set) plus you are doing a removeall.

Comment: Potentially, putting all elements of `ListB` into a `Set` will have better performance, because `ListA.removeAll(ListB)` has **quadratic** time complexity, while `ListA.removeAll(SetListB)` has **linear** time complexity. So the overhead of putting elements into a `Set` is negligible compared to quadratic time complexity.

Comment: Can you offer a Big O estimation for this?

Comment: I'm sorry, I had wrong input data. Strings in lists had letters in different case. When I used .toLowerCase to all strings in lists ListA.removeAll(ListB) worked fine. Changed original post. But with sets instead of lists it works faster so thanks for answers, they were useful.

Comment: @LastFreeNickname I've added the Big O estimation

Answer (score 2):

Create a set for the 400 000 names in `namesListB`. Then use this set to remove the undesired elements of `namesListA`.

```
List<String> namesListA = new ArrayList<>(/*50 000 strings*/);
List<String> namesListB = new ArrayList<>(/*400 000 strings*/);

Set<String> undesiredNames = new HashSet<>(namesListB);

for (String name : namesListA) {
    if (undesiredNames.contains(name)) {
        namesListA.remove(name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to parallelize the removal. The lists `namesListA` and `namesListB` can be grouped by starting character; then the removal could be done group-wise in parallel and the resulting lists could be concatenated again.

Assuming some standard Latin alphabet, this would result in roughly 26 groups which could be processed in parallel. If 4 threads can be run in parallel, I would expect a significant speedup.

Comment: He just mentioned string, String can be any literal starting character - How can we assume it to be just Alphabets ??? . Though it says names list, It can be any 'thing's' name.

Comment: In this particular example Strings are names and can contain only letters.

Comment: Using the first `char` value, this will still be a number, more groups but the idea is still valid. Using a Map to store the different groups created and you are good to launch Thread on every groups.

Comment: @SrikanthA Thanks for the critical comment; the 'Latin alphabet' part was just for an illustration of the idea. If the full unicode range can occur in the input, there will be far more groups. However then, the input can be grouped by range of the starting glyph, not the starting glyph itself.

Comment: @Hodor, Grouping is a good Idea - as long as the number of possible starting character is not too high.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use an `HashSet` instead of a `List` to store the `String`s of the biggest collection in order to know whether the collection contains or not a given `String` with a time complexity of `O(1)` instead of `O(n)`, then use `removeAll(Collection<?> c)` to keep only the `String`s that are not in the second collection as next:

```
List<String> namesListA = new ArrayList<>(/*50 000 strings*/);
Set<String> namesSetB = new HashSet<>(/*400 000 strings*/);
namesListA.removeAll(namesSetB);
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing a list of removeAll is probably a better solution, Considering you have both the variables with 50k and 400k sized Lists

```
namesListA.removeAll(namesListB);
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's not important which element is duplicate but only **if** there is any you can let the Collections do the trick for you.

```
int sizeA = listA.size();
int sizeB = listB.size();

Set merger = new HashSet((sizeA+sizeB)*someLoadFactor);
merger.addAll(listA);
merger.addAll(listB);
// Sets do not contain duplicates!

if (merger.size() < sizeA + sizeB){
    return true;
}
return false;
```

This runs in O(i+j) so efficiently **O(n)**!